# ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, always broadcast when registering a receiver?

Tags: android

I'm registering a receiver to capture the ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION *in code* i.e. I am not registering it in the application manifest. All is working fine but I notice that I automatically receive a broadcast as soon as I register my receiver and despite the network being already on.

My question is can I rely on this automatic broadcast to check whether the network is available or not i.e. not explicitly call methods to check the network?

I was only expecting a broadcast when a network changed and not upon registering my receiver, however the fact that I do receive a broadcast is very useful but can I rely on it. Is this a documented action?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that's called [sticky broadcasts](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendStickyBroadcast%28android.content.Intent%29). Sticky broadcasts are sent to receiver as soon as `registerBroadcast` is called.

Comment: Am I correct when I say that the doc doesn't mention the fact that this particular broadcast is sticky? And that maybe means that we shouldn't depend on this.

Comment: What about BoD's comment (I came to this question wondering about the same thing) ? Maybe fill an issue at google (better change the docs than the behavior) ? See also : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427812/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-triggered-when-registered