# android: ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, send broadcast when the net connected state has not changed

Tags: android

I registered a broadcast to get ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, code is:

```
registerReceiver(mNetwrokBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
```

and the receiver is:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mNetwrokBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        boolean isConnected = false;
        NetworkInfo mNetworkInfo = intent
                .getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
        NetworkInfo.State state = (mNetworkInfo == null ? NetworkInfo.State.UNKNOWN
                : mNetworkInfo.getState());

        switch (state) {
        case CONNECTED:
            isConnected = true;
            break;

        case DISCONNECTING:
            if (intent.getBooleanExtra(
                    ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false))
                isConnected = false;
            else {
                isConnected = true;
            }
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }


        if (isConnected) {
            mPopwin.onDismiss();
            init();

        }
    }
};
```

but I found when net always connected , it also send broadcast, why???
there is a same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670514/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-always-broadcast-when-registering-a-rec) , I can't got it.

Edit:
I means, I register a broadcast that the filter is "ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION" in init of a activity, when the net has always connected, I start the activity,  the function "onReceive" executed; In [google doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) said "A change in network connectivity has occurred", but there is no change in network, why execute onReceive ?

Comment: Your question is not clear. please elaborate or make your problem more clear.

Comment: See my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/a/16428823/769265

Answer (score 1):

Since CONNECTIVITY_ACTION is stick broadcast hence it keep on calling onRecevie to remove it u can use removeStickyBroadcast (Intent intent) [DOC](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#removeStickyBroadcast(android.content.Intent))