# BroadcastReceiver onReceive triggered when registered

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver which is being triggered the moment it's registered (and subsequently retriggered with onPause / onResume), surely this is the wrong behaviour? Have I missed something here?

```
class FooActivity extends Activity {    

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        broadcastReceiver = new FooBroadcastReceiver();
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(connectivityReceiver, intentFilter);         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(connectivityReceiver);
    }


class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {       
        if (connectivityAction(intent)) {
            Log.d("footag", "onReceive");
        }
    }

    private boolean connectivityAction(Intent intent) {
        return ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction());
    }

}
```

Comment: there is nothing wrong in it.have a look at docs : `http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html`

Comment: @Adam the `MyBroadcastReceiver` is static in your example right?

Comment: Also you can do this `NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);` to gather more information on why your BroadcastReciever is being called

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for the answers! My solution was a result of them all, by switching to a manifest declared receiver and enabling/disabling the receiver component in onResume/onPause stopped the sticky nature of the receiver. And by enabling/disabling the component I can have piece of mind that I'm a second class citizen.

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setReceiverState(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    setReceiverState(PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED);
}


private void setReceiverState(int receiverState) {
    ComponentName receiver = new ComponentName(this, FooBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PackageManager pm = this.getPackageManager();
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(receiver, receiverState,       
    PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.example.receiver.FooBroadcastReceiver">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Means you can't make a jar and will have to be an Android Library :-)

Comment: in the case of a library, the client would add the receiver to the manifest and it could still be a .jar. Although a lib and manifest merger would be nicer :(

Comment: BroadcastReceivers like this, are no longer triggered when targeting API Level 23 or higher. You have to register/unregister them in onResume()/onPause().

Answer (score 18):

The `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` broadcast seems to be sticky on some devices (even though the documentation implies that it is not). This means that when you register the receiver it will immediately call `onReceive()` with the most recently sent broadcast. Since you are registering and unregistering in `onPause()` and `onResume()` you will get a lot of calls to `onReceive()`. You might want to do this in a different way.

Comment: i m facing same issue ..m registering in onStartCommand of service :     IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
                    ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
            registerReceiver(networkStateReceiver, filter);

Comment: @DIVA As the OP said, use a manifest-declared receiver and don't register the receiver in code.

Comment: m facing strange issue here : can u plz refer this http://pastie.org/pastes/9503426/text when i use action other than wifi and run code it wont print "In onreceive method" but when i use         IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(
                ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION); it prints which knowing if wifi is off or on ..whats the reason

Comment: @DIVA please open a new question for this. You'll get a lot more attention than burying your question in a comment.

Comment: Found this out the hard way. To anyone reading this, to exclude the sticky one check for isInitialStickyBroadcast()

Comment: @DavidWasser can you please specify that **different way**.Manifest Registered Receivers are history now.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another solution that worked for me:

```
class FooActivity extends Activity {    

    private Intent mReceiverRegisteringIntent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        broadcastReceiver = new FooBroadcastReceiver();
        intentFilter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mReceiverRegisteringIntent = registerReceiver(connectivityReceiver, intentFilter);         
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(connectivityReceiver);
    }


    private class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {       
            if (connectivityAction(intent)) {
                Log.d("footag", "onReceive");
                //if mReceiverRegisteringIntent is not null, then this is the sticky
                //broadcast received when registering the receiver for the first time
                if (mReceiverRegisteringIntent != null) {
                    //set it to null for future broadcasts
                    mReceiverRegisteringIntent = null;
                    return; //do nothing
                }

                //logic for future broadcasts
                ...
            }
        }

        private boolean connectivityAction(Intent intent) {
            return ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction());
        }
    }

}
```

I'm assuming that `MyBroadcastReceiver` is an inner class for `FooActivity` so it can access `mReceiverRegisteringIntent`

Comment: I agree, this is the right solution! `registerReceiver()` returns "The first sticky intent found or null if there are none". So it can be used for detection.

Answer (score -2):

remove the following two lines they won't be triggered in onPause and onResume!

```
registerReceiver(connectivityReceiver, intentFilter);
unregisterReceiver(connectivityReceiver);
```

Comment: why wont they be applied?

Comment: Good advise. Uninstall your app and there wont be any notifications :D