# OnReceive() method auto triggered

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have created the one receiver inside an Activity for when internet is connected auto calling web service.

Code like

```
//Create receiver for while network will come auto call webservice

private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
        if (!noConnectivity) {
            bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            callAuthorizeWebservice();
        } else {
            bar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, "Check Your Internet connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        this.registerReceiver(this.mConnReceiver,
                new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    }
```

When I open that Activity the `onReceive()` is method called everytime.
How to avoid calling it the first time (when opening that Activity)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427812/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-triggered-when-registered

Comment: "How to avoid calling it the first time"---Did you mean avoid calling it Every time except first time?

Answer (score 3):

The broadcast is sent when you register for the first time(cf sticky broadcast), a solution is to use `isInitialStickyBroadcast` in the `onReceive` callback  of your `BroadcastReceiver` to know if you are actually proceeding a sticky broadcast and act accordingly  ([BroadcastReceiver : isInitialStickyBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#isInitialStickyBroadcast()))