# I am receiving "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" as soon as Registering BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I register a broadcast on **runtime** to receive "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"

```
   IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED");
    broadcastReceiverAction = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED")) {
/*I get this action as soon as calling registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverAction, intentFilter);*/
    }
    }
    }
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverAction, intentFilter);
```

**Issue**: This gets the broadcast action as soon as registering the receiver.
I got this on **Android API 26 & Higher** Which I can not declare "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" in Manifest. (No Longer Supported by Android System)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BroadcastReceiver onReceive triggered when registered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16427812/broadcastreceiver-onreceive-triggered-when-registered)

Comment: I got this on Android API 26 & Higher Which I can not declare "android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" in Manifest. (No Longer Supported by Android System)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**Simple Solution**]

Problem is Sticky Broadcasts which trigger at the moment of registration.
To avoid this I simply add another parameter to restrict the process.
I defined a static variable

```
public static boolean triggerBroadcast = false;
```

Then I change it to after registering the broadcast by few second delay.

```
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiverAction, intentFilter);
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
triggerWifiBroadcast = true;
}
}, 3000);
```

Then onReceive() I compare intent.getAction with this

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED") && triggerBroadcast ) {
//
}
```

Then you can change it to **false** whenever decide to unregister the broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 1):

To check network connectivity state change you can do it programmatically. It supports API 21+.

```
    public class ConnectionStateMonitor extends ConnectivityManager.NetworkCallback {
    public final String TAG = ConnectionStateMonitor.class.getSimpleName();
                    private boolean isLost = false;


                    final NetworkRequest networkRequest;
                    Context context;
                    private ConnectionStateMonitor instance;
                    private boolean isLost = false;

                    private ConnectionStateMonitor() {
                        networkRequest = new NetworkRequest.Builder()
                                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_CELLULAR)
                                .addTransportType(NetworkCapabilities.TRANSPORT_WIFI)
                                .build();
                    }

                    public synchronized ConnectionStateMonitor getInstance() {
                        if (instance == null) {
                            instance = new ConnectionStateMonitor();
                        }
                        return instance;
                    }

                    public void enable(Context context) {
                        try {
                            if (context == null) return;
                            this.context = context;
                            ConnectivityManager connectivityManager =
                                    (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                            connectivityManager.registerNetworkCallback(networkRequest, this);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onAvailable(Network network) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onAvailable called " + 
                                network.toString());
                                if (isLost) {
                                isLost = false;}
                       // when network available called it
                    }


                    @Override
                    public void onLost(Network network) {
                        super.onLost(network);
                        isLost = true;
                        // when network lost called it
                        Log.i(TAG, "onLost called ");
                    }
                }
```

Comment: When the network is available it triggers the onAvailable() as soon as calling registerNetworkCallback() so my main problem still remains. I got another solution that I will post asap.

Comment: please check my latest updated code. It will prevent for the first time call and work well for all uses. Thanks

Comment: As I posted yesterday the solution of simple variable to add extra restriction on getting the intent action.