# Why receiver receive broadcast every time the onResume() method activated?

Tags: android, broadcast, onresume

In my onresume() of activity, I have this

> IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
>   intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
>   registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);

Every time the onResume() activate, **mReceiver** always received a broadcast have the action of **ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION**

That's strange, because my networkstate is in a stable wifi and does not changed at all.

Comment: It's better to check whether BReceiver is already registered or not before registering it again and again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems **sticky broadcasts** is a common problem for action ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION,
Follow the instruction I tried to describe the receiver in XML but it seems NOT OK with that
AT last,I used a flexible method to resolve this:Since **everytime** in Onresume will send that broadcast,I set a boolean value to be 'false',when the onresume called the receiver for the first time,the program will do nothing but just set this boolean value to 'true'.
Then when CONNECTIVITY changed,it will go normal process.
This seems not an elegant method ,but it worked in my app.

Answer (score 2):

every time onresume is activited , registerReceiver is called one more each time.
registerReceiver sends bck  **sticky broadcasts**. Sticky broadcasts are sent to receiver as soon as registerBroadcast is called.

you can use **unregisterReceiver** or check you will have to check whether you have already registered and skip , if yes..

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation for registerReceiver (BroadcastReceiver receiver, IntentFilter filter):

> The system may broadcast Intents that are "sticky" -- these stay around after the broadcast as finished, to be sent to any later registrations. If your IntentFilter matches one of these sticky Intents, that Intent will be returned by this function and sent to your receiver as if it had just been broadcast.

Though you are just registering your receiver right now but it's up to the system when to broadcast that Intent and since that intent is a sticky one so it gets broadcasted as soon as you register.

Check out this [ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION, always broadcast when registering a receiver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6670514/connectivitymanager-connectivity-action-always-broadcast-when-registering-a-rec)

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to use `isInitialStickyBroadcast` in the `onReceive` callback  of your `BroadcastReceiver` to know if you are actually proceeding a sticky broadcast and act accordingly  ([BroadcastReceiver : isInitialStickyBroadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#isInitialStickyBroadcast()))